# Checking whether this set of matrices forms a group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

> Let $G$ be the set of matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ 0&c \end{pmatrix}$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are integers modulo 5, and $a\neq 0\neq c$. Show that $G$ forms a group under matrix multiplication (which can be assumed to be associative).

Checking for closure seems relatively straight forward. Associativity is already assumed so we don't need to check that. The identity I got as just the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. The problem I'm having is with checking the existence of an inverse.

It seems straightforward that an inverse to any matrix in $G$ exists since the determinant is non-zero and so they are all invertible, but I'm slightly confused by the modulo arithmetic part. Since it doesn't seem obvious to me that the inverse modulo 5 should necessarily be in $G$. I've looked at the solution and they explicitly wrote out an inverse as:
$$ A^{-1}= \frac{1}{ac}\begin{pmatrix} c&-b \\ 0&a \end{pmatrix} $$
but I'm confused as to how this works since how is $1/a$ even in the set of integers modulo 5 (unless $a=1$).

It seems to me that the inverse should have to satisfy:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ 0&c \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_1&b_1\\ 0&c_1 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} aa_1&ab_1+bc_1\\ 0&cc_1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
so for example surely we'd need to find an $a_1$ such that:
$$aa_1=1\mod 5$$

---

But I'm not entirely sure whether any of this is correct, or even necessary, since the solution I looked at didn't mention anything about it.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a}$ is just notation. $2\cdot 3 = 1 mod 5$ and $4\cdot 4=1 mod 5$ so every non-zero number has an inverse.

Comment: @JohnDouma yeah that makes sense. I was just confused when the solution didn't mention anything to do with the modulo bit. Though I've not really used/studied modulo arithmetic yet so maybe it's obvious and I just didn't see it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of $1,2,3,4$ has a unique multiplicative inverse. For example, $1^{-1}=1$, $2^{-1}=3$, $3^{-1}=2$, $4^{-1}=4$. The whole thing will be easy if you think these matrices with entries from the field $Z_5$. Here, $5$ is a prime, that's why it's worked. If $5$ is replaced by any prime $p$, then each element $1,2,3,…,p-1$ has a unique multiplicative inverse (because, $U_p$ forms a group with respect to multiplication modulo p).

Comment: I think that's what I was forgetting, since it's clear when you view it like that. Thanks!